# Drop Down list in php (help)

Tags: php, select, drop-down-menu

Well, this is my first question in stackoverflow. I hope that you can help me!

I would like to make a select box or a drop down list, if you prefer

So, i have this php code:

```
<?php $i = 0; ?>
                            <?php $orders = osc_list_orders();
                            foreach($orders as $label => $params) {
                                $orderType = ($params['iOrderType'] == 'asc') ? '0' : '1'; ?>
                                <?php if(osc_search_order() == $params['sOrder'] && osc_search_order_type() == $orderType) { ?>
                                    <a class="current" href="<?php echo osc_update_search_url($params); ?>"><?php echo $label; ?></a>
                                <?php } else { ?>
                                    <a href="<?php echo osc_update_search_url($params); ?>"><?php echo $label; ?></a>
                                <?php } ?>
                                <?php if ($i != count($orders)-1) { ?>
                                    <span>|</span>
                                <?php } ?>
                                <?php $i++; ?>
                            <?php } ?>
```

I have tried to do something like this:

```
function osc_list_orders_drop() {

$orders = osc_list_orders();
echo '<select name="order" id="order" ONCHANGE="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">';




    foreach($orders as $label => $params){
       $orderType = ($params['iOrderType'] == 'asc') ? '0' : '1';
        echo '<option value="'.osc_update_search_url($params).'">';
        echo $label; 
        echo'</option>';   

    }

   echo'</select>';
}
```

But the first option is not stored, so when i select one option and then try to select the first one, the first one never works.

Can you help me?

Thx

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "so when i select one option and then try to select the first one, the first one never works." What do you mean by it never works?

Comment: I don´t know if you know osclass. This is for osclass. See in here what i´m talking about: http://teste.goodluckwith.us/for-sale .When you select Lower price first, everything ok. But when you try to select newly listed it doesn´t work. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a blank option tag in the select, it will allow the change to trigger.

```
function osc_list_orders_drop() {

    $orders = osc_list_orders();
    echo '<select name="order" id="order" ONCHANGE="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">';

    echo '<option></option>';

    foreach($orders as $label => $params){
        $orderType = ($params['iOrderType'] == 'asc') ? '0' : '1';
        echo '<option value="'.osc_update_search_url($params).'">';
        echo $label; 
        echo'</option>';   
    }

    echo'</select>';
}
```

A better option would be to add a selected="selected" to the current filter's option tag.

Comment: It worked, but now i have an option in blank. There isn´t a way to make this without that blank space?